# How to pass raw string to Command in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a fully formed string of the command I want to run with https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html

For example `"blah -a 'test arg'"`, how do I pass it in without parsing it myself which would require parsing quote group into an arg?

I tried passing the rest of the args after splitting.

Comment: What is the syntax of the string you have? The answer varies by platform. The docs you linked show how to pass a command to `cmd /C` on Windows and `sh -c` on Unix.

Comment: Basically I have a string: "python3.10 -c 'for i in range(100): print(1)'", and need to parse out the quote group correctly to pass it in as an arg.

Comment: The docs show `Command::new("sh").arg("-c").arg(command)`. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes. It works but not what I need. I need to run the program directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another recommended crate for this purpose is [shell-words](https://github.com/tmiasko/shell-words).
It offers potentially better parsing with the difference that it returns a vector of Strings, not references.

Ref: [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53498414/how-do-i-pass-a-single-string-with-multiple-arguments-to-stdprocesscommand/53518384)

Answer (score 2):

You can call out to a shell to run the command. Actually the docs you've linked to have an example of doing just that.

```rust
use std::process::Command;

let output = if cfg!(target_os = "windows") {
    Command::new("cmd")
            .args(["/C", "echo hello"])
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
} else {
    Command::new("sh")
            .arg("-c")
            .arg("echo hello")
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")
};

let hello = output.stdout;
```

Just replace both instances of `"echo hello"` with the command you want to run.

Comment: It's different. I need to run the program directly to access its running memory.

Comment: You might want to mention that in your question above.

Comment: Well I asked how to parse the process command arguments directly and you came up with a something unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I found [shlex](https://docs.rs/shlex/latest/shlex/) which is a lexer for shell words.

Comment: You could improve this answer and describe what you learned and how you use it. Just a link is not very useful for a future reader.